# Django registration opens other template

Tags: python, django, templates, redirect

I am pretty new to Django but have gone through a few tutorials and have taken it upon myself to create an app very similar to the Tango with Django walkthrough app, rango.

Everything has worked so far, but when I attempt to add a registration feature, the link brings me to the wrong template.  I think this be because I have migrated parts from another app and so perhaps the webpage is looking for something that isn't there?

Here is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from address_book.models import Client, UserProfile

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Name: ")
    phone = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Phone Number: ")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Address: ")
    desired_weight = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Desired Weight: ")
    start_weight = forms.IntegerField(help_text="Start Weight: ")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    comments = forms.CharField(max_length=500, help_text="Comments: ")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Client
        fields = ('name', 'phone', 'address', 'desired_weight', 'start_weight',)

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Client(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        desired_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        start_weight = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
        comments = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.slug = slugify(self.name)
                super(Client, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def __unicode__(self):
                return self.name

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from address_book.forms import ClientForm, UserForm, UserProfileForm
from address_book.models import Client


def index(request):

    client_list = Client.objects.all().order_by('name')
    # Construct a dictionary to pass to the template engine as its context.
    # Note the key boldmessage is the same as {{ boldmessage }} in the template!
    context_dict = {'clients': client_list}

    # Return a rendered response to send to the client.
    # We make use of the shortcut function to make our lives easier.
    # Note that the first parameter is the template we wish to use.

    return render(request, 'address_book/index.html', context_dict)

def add_client(request):
    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClientForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save(commit=True)

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = ClientForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'address_book/add_client.html', {'form': form})

def client(request, client_name_slug):

    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        # Can we find a category name slug with the given name?
        # If we can't, the .get() method raises a DoesNotExist exception.
        # So the .get() method returns one model instance or raises an exception.
        client = Client.objects.get(slug=client_name_slug)
        context_dict['client_name'] = client.name
        context_dict['client_name_slug'] = client_name_slug
        context_dict['client_phone'] = client.phone
        context_dict['client_address'] = client.address
        context_dict['desired_weight'] = client.desired_weight
        context_dict['start_weight'] = client.start_weight
        context_dict['comments'] = client.comments

        # Retrieve all of the associated pages.
        # Note that filter returns >= 1 model instance.
#        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        # Adds our results list to the template context under name pages.
#        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        # We also add the category object from the database to the context dictionary.
        # We'll use this in the template to verify that the category exists.
        context_dict['client'] = client
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
        pass

    # Go render the response and return it to the client.
    print context_dict
    return render(request, 'address_book/client.html', context_dict)

def register(request):

    # A boolean value for telling the template whether the registration was successful.
    # Set to False initially. Code changes value to True when registration succeeds.
    registered = False

    # If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Attempt to grab information from the raw form information.
        # Note that we make use of both UserForm and UserProfileForm.
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

        # If the two forms are valid...
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            # Save the user's form data to the database.
            user = user_form.save()

            # Now we hash the password with the set_password method.
            # Once hashed, we can update the user object.
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            # Now sort out the UserProfile instance.
            # Since we need to set the user attribute ourselves, we set commit=False.
            # This delays saving the model until we're ready to avoid integrity problems.
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            # Did the user provide a profile picture?
            # If so, we need to get it from the input form and put it in the UserProfile model.
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

            # Now we save the UserProfile model instance.
            profile.save()

            # Update our variable to tell the template registration was successful.
            registered = True

        # Invalid form or forms - mistakes or something else?
        # Print problems to the terminal.
        # They'll also be shown to the user.
        else:
            print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

    # Not a HTTP POST, so we render our form using two ModelForm instances.
    # These forms will be blank, ready for user input.
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileForm()

    # Render the template depending on the context.
    return render(request,
            'address_book/register.html',
            {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

    <h1>Register with 3010 Weightloss !</h1>

    {% if registered %}
    <a href="/address_book/">Return to the homepage.</a><br />
    {% else %}
    Rango says: <strong>register here!</strong><br />

    <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/address_book/register/"
            enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {% csrf_token %}

        <!-- Display each form. The as_p method wraps each element in a paragraph
             (<p>) element. This ensures each element appears on a new line,
             making everything look neater. -->
        {{ user_form.as_p }}
        {{ profile_form.as_p }}

        <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    {% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from address_book import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^add_client/$', views.add_client, name='add_client'),
        url(r'^(?P<client_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.client, name='client'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register, name = 'register'),
)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

    <head>
        <title>Rango</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h2>Current Clients:</h2>
            {% for client in clients %}
                <li><a href="{% url 'client'  client.slug %}">{{ client.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

and finally my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Address_book</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body_block %}{% endblock %}
    </body>

    <h2> Need to make changes? </h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'add_client' %}">Add new client</a></li>
        <li><a href="/address_book/register/">Register here</a></li>
    </ul>
</html>
```

Like I said above, when I click the link to register in index.py, it brings me to another template, client.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that `/address_book/register/` matches your client url, which comes before the register URL. To fix that, one way to fix this would be to switch the order of the URL strings:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^add_client/$', views.add_client, name='add_client'),
        url(r'^register/$', views.register, name = 'register'),
        url(r'^(?P<client_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', views.client, name='client'),
)
```

However, it would be better to call the URL by its name in your base.html instead of relying on the order of the URL strings:

```
# base.html
...
<li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register here</a></li>
...
```

Comment: Changiong the order worked, but even when I call the URL properly, if they are in the wrong order, it does the same thing.